# django admin attribute to override error_message in modelForm Meta for Regex, and variables in error_message strings

Tags: python, django, validation, meta, error-messaging

I've got some validators defined on my ModelForm in Django Admin:

```
class AddressesAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddressesAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['unitorsuitenumber'].validators = [MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)]
        self.fields['streetaddress'].validators = [RegexValidator(regExAlphanumericSpacesCommasPeriods)]
```

In Meta for ModelForm, I can override the error_messages:

```
        error_messages = {
            'unitorsuitenumber': {
                'min_value': _('Ensure Unit/Suite Number value is at least %(limit_value)d ' +
                              '(Current value is %(show_value)d).'),
                'max_value': _('Ensure Unit/Suite Number value is not more than %(limit_value)d ' +
                               '(Current value is %(show_value)d).'),
            },
            'streetaddress': {
                'regexvalidator': _('Only numbers, letters, periods, spaces and dashes are allowed'),
            },
        }
```

Two questions:

1. For the RegEx Validator, the error msg is not being replaced with my custom one. On the validators for Min and Max Values, I have to specify min_value and max_value for the attributes to override the message. But for the RegEx validator, which attribute do I override? Furthermore, for any given validator, how can I know the proper attribute to override for the error_message? I want to do this here in Meta, not somehow else.
2. I see that for MinValue and MaxValue Validators, there are variables available to me in the string, %(limit_value)d and %(show_value)d. I would like to know how can I know which variables are available to me for any given validator. And, is there a variable that I can use for verbose_name, so something like %(verbose_name)d? For example, I could replace my hard-coded Unit/Suite Number with a variable, and then be able to make the error message generic.

Comment: and, I have tried to substitute 'message' for 'regexvalidator', and it still does not work.

Comment: however, if I add message in __init__ where the validator itself is declared, I can get it to work  self.fields['streetaddress'].validators = [RegexValidator(regExAlphanumericSpacesCommasPeriods, message='123')]

Comment: how can I get this to work in meta instead?